# Room UPDATE not working (Tried many variations)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

Ok I have 2 Entities both related. ConnectionEntity and ChatEntity. One to many relationship between them. One connection can have multiple chats.

Let us look at how I have defined connection entity

1. Connections Entity (id of type INT is primary key, autogenerate is set to TRUE)
2. partner_uid column is a unique column

Let us look at how I have defined chat entity

1. Chat Entity (id of type INT is primary key, autogenerate is set to TRUE)
2. message_id column is a unique column
3. Also chat_partner_uid referes to partner_uid of ConnectionEntity (chat_partner_uid in chatEntity refers to child column and partner_uid in connectionEntity refers to the parent column and this is the one - many relationship)

What works:

1. Inserting a connectionEntity works
2. Deleting a connectionEntity or all entities works

What is the issue:

1. Update operation just does not work. I have tried with all conflict strategies and also tried passing in the same entity with autogenerated id by getting the id first

What I have done:

1. I have followed some stack overflow posts and used the upsert strategy
2. First try inserting with onconflict = ABORT, catch the exception if the row already exists and then call update
3. I also first get the ID from room because ids are autogenerated, populate the new connection entity with the same ID and call update but it just does not work. Data remains the same

My ConnectionEntity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "connection_table", indices = [Index("partner_uid", unique = true)])
data class ConnectionEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "partner_uid")
    var partnerUid: String,

    var connectionMedium: String = ValueStrings.connectionMediumChat.stringValue,
    var firstName: String = "",
    var isDisconnected: Boolean = false,
    var profileImageUrl: String = "",
    var unReadMessages: Int = 0
)
```

My ChatEntity Class

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "chat_table",
    indices = [Index("message_id", unique = true)],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = ConnectionEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["partner_uid"],
            childColumns = ["chat_partner_uid"],
            onDelete = CASCADE,
            deferred = true
        )
    ]
)
data class ChatEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = 0,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message_id")
    var messageId: String,

    var fromId: String = "",
    var messageText: String = "",
    var messageTime: Int = 0,
    var toId: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "chat_partner_uid", index = true)
    var chatPartnerUid: String
)
```

Here is the DAO

```
@Dao
interface ConnectionChatDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    suspend fun insertConnection(connectionEntity: ConnectionEntity)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateConnection(connectionEntity: ConnectionEntity)

    @Transaction
    suspend fun upsert(connectionEntity: ConnectionEntity) {
        try {
            insertConnection(connectionEntity)
        } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException) {
            val currentId = getConnection(connectionEntity.partnerUid)?.id
            connectionEntity.id = currentId
            updateConnection(connectionEntity)
        }
    }

    @Query("DELETE FROM connection_table")
    suspend fun flushAllData()
}
```

As requested...This is how I call the function. I use a repository pattern from the view model

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val repository = AccessRepository(ConnectionChatUserDatabase.getInstance(application))

    fun updateConnectionNameInRoom() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val connectionEntity = ConnectionEntity(
                partnerUid = "def",
                connectionMedium = "Chat",
                firstName = "Jake",
                isDisconnected = false,
                profileImageUrl = "www.google.com",
                unReadMessages = 0
            )

            val response = repository.upsertData(connectionEntity)
            if (!response.isOperationComplete) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "There was an error")
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Success")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the repository class

```
class AccessRepository(private val database: ConnectionChatUserDatabase) {

    //Room
    suspend fun upsertDataToRoom(connectionEntity: ConnectionEntity): AccessRepositoryProperty<String>{
        return try {
            database.connectionChatDao.upsert(connectionEntity)
            AccessRepositoryProperty(null, property = "Success", isOperationComplete = true)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            AccessRepositoryProperty(e, property = "upsertError", isOperationComplete = false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code where update is called.

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni I have added the code as requested. I am using a repository pattern

Comment: Have you tried running raw Update query just to check whether that works? `@Query(update table_name set field=new_value where condition)`. Also try running this query from database inspector.

Comment: Yes that worked. It is weird because when I mark a suspend DAO function as @Transaction and try an upsert logic, the above problem occurs. I solved it by calling it separately as separate functions instead of wrapping them into a single function

Comment: Even normal @-Update works as long as I don't try to wrap multiple DAO calls within a single DAO function marked as @Transaction.

Comment: Though you are catching the exception, `@Transaction` fails if exception occurs, right?

Comment: Actually that is not a problem. Let me make this simple. Notice the DAO function upsert. It first tries an insert and I am catching in case of SQLITE exception. It catches when it realizes that the data cannot be inserted because there is already a data existing with required ID and unique values. So it tries the update function which I call in catch block. But I read somewhere that before updating, I also need to pass in the correct ID and since ID is auto generated, I need to get that first. Then I call update but I find out that nothing happens. Data remains as it is not updated.